# Why divide a downspout or require an extra sleeve?

Tags: gutters, downspout

A gutter installer just put gutters and downspouts on my new addition.  Is this some new technique that I am not privy to?  What would be the purpose of doing it this way?

[image]

Comment: It was probably short and he had a couple of short pieces left over from another job.  He used them instead of cutting into a long piece and charging you for a long piece.

Comment: IDK why TWO extra pieces, Crip is probably right, but one short piece attached near the bottom of the spout allows you to remove it and clean leaves and crap out of the spout and snake the drain if needed without climbing ladders.

Comment: That band at the top appears to be a strap for holding the downspout against the wall.

Comment: Using multiple pieces here also allows you to slide one piece up in case you ever need to access that adapter at the bottom to unclog it or something.

Comment: @Huesmann Put that in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a gutter pro, but my speculation would be that using multiple pieces here allows you to slide one piece up in case you ever need to access that adapter at the bottom to unclog it or something.  (Some installations may be flexible enough to separate parts without sliding multiple sections, but some may not.)

Comment: As I read this again, I wonder if the identical sized pieces will actually allow this to work properly. I can't imagine any other reason though for doing this.

Comment: Typically the upper one is crimped slightly, reducing the size enough to allow it to slip into the bottom one.